# Return input parameters as they are in R

Tags: r, function, input, output

I have a function that should return all my input parameters.

This is what I have so far:

```
f <- function(.variables,
              .numbers){
  as.list(match.call())[-1]
}

Test <- f(c("Species", "Sepal.Length"), 1:5)

Test$.variables
Test$.numbers
```

What I really want to have i.e. in .numbers the real numbers as they are, here from class `numeric` so that I can do operations like `Test$.numbers + 2` with it. My function has many input parameters so I don't want to have a solution like `return(.numbers)` or `return(list(.variables, .numbers))`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can evaluate the arguments of the function :

```
f <- function(.variables,  .numbers) {
  lapply(as.list(match.call())[-1], eval)
}
Test <- f(c("Species", "Sepal.Length"), 1:5)

Test$.variables
#[1] "Species"      "Sepal.Length"
Test$.numbers
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```